# How to inherit hr.employee module in openerp(odoo)

Tags: odoo

This is my code and i am getting this error. I tried to inherit the hr.employee and in hr.employee model, I had added four custom fields and one of them is 'x_doj'

```
    ParseError: "ValidateError
    Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

    Error details:
    Field `x_doj` does not exist

    Error context:
    View `hr.employee`
    [view_id: 939, xml_id: n/a, model: hr.employee, parent_id: 813]" while parsing /home/administrator/Sub_Station/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/hredit1/hredit_view.xml:5, near
    <record id="hr_inheritedview_employee_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">hr.employee</field>
                <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
                <field name="type">form</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <notebook position="inside">
                        <page string="Empl Resource">   
                            <field name="deal" nolabel="1"/> 
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </field>


            </record>

my hredit.py 
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

    class empl(osv.Model):
        _inherit='hr.employee'
        _columns = {
            'deal':fields.char('done',size=20)
        }

    empl()





this my xml code hredit.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="hr_inheritedview_employee_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="work_phone" position="after">  
                        <field name="deal" /> 
                    </field>

            </field>


        </record>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

in hr.employee.form also tried

my *openerp*.py file

```
{
    'name': 'Hr Edit',
    'version':'1.0',
    'description': """
        Hr Edit
        - Epics
    """,
    'author': 'Shridhar',
    'depends': ['base_setup'],
    'data': ['hredit_view.xml',],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

and in *init.py*  i have done import hredit

Comment: Please provide enough detail, as your error does not related to your current code you have provided here, please update it with your py and xml where you have added custom fields.

Comment: i was remove notebook and page tags from .xml file this is error i am gettin
<record id="hr_inheritedview_employee_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
   <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
   <field name="type">form</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="work_phone" position="after"> 
      <field name="deal"/> 
     </field>
    
   </field>
    
    
  </record>

Answer (score 1):

Hello Shridhar Ivani,

In this case you must need to set the dependent module name in your **__openeerp__.py** file.

hear hr.employee model comes from the **HR Module** but you have not yet set as  dependent module as the hr in your **__openerp__.py** file

You can add the hr from the depends in your **__openerp__.py** file and upgrade your module list as well as your module then every things will work fine.

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Try to check again with update all module with your db name and restart the server

Comment: please send me that __openerp__.py code i ahve done like this

Comment: {
    'name': 'Hr Edit',
    'version':'1.0',
    'description': """
        Hr Edit
        - Epics
    """,
    'author': 'Shridhar',
    'depends': ['base_setup','hr'],
    'data': ['hredit_view.xml',],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve in **openerp.py**

This is my solution:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': 'nombre de modulo',

    'summary': """

        """,

    'description': """
    descripcion
    """,

    'author': '--',
    'website': "http://www.yoursite.com",
    'category': '--',
    'version': '0.1',
    **'depends': ['base', 'hr', 'hr_expense'],**
    'data': [
        'views/gi_hr_expense_view.xml',
    ],

    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```